# How to make a folder which contains php scripts into a private folder?

Tags: php, webserver, client, vps

Not sure how to better phrase the title.

We have an iOS game which connects with a MySQL database on our VPS via PHP. Now we don't know a great deal about the server side of things, so we got it all working, the game is released and people are able to update their scores etc.

The problem is that the only way we were able to get it all to work was to put our game directory into our public_html directory. This means that if anyone types www.ourwebsitename/gamefoldername into a browser they get the index of that folder. If you click one of the folders in there, it actually returns a table with all of the data in our database, which is obviously not secure.

Is there a way to make this directory private, and if so how would this affect our app when it tries to connect to the server?

Comment: just change the folder permission at server.

Comment: Will that not cause problems when the app attempts to connect? Given that the app is already built and so will not have a password etc. Apologies for being so naive,  but neither of us have really done much server stuff before

Comment: You need to specify how exactly your app is connecting to the server. Via normal http requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are alots of way to prevent this :

Some are below.

1) Put a index.php in this and every folder www.ourwebsitename/gamefoldername  and this file should redirect the user who provide this url to main/login page. This is simple but not a great way.

2) Use . ht access file http://www.htaccess-guide.com/redirects/ . Please get details from here.

Comment: Ok well you have a few upvotes already and the data is not particularly private (mainly just scores and userID's) so the redirect should be ok for now. For future projects I'll use some kind of password system to block the directory.
Thanks

Comment: Yes , That is possible with .htaccess

Comment: Which redirection you are using First or second ??

Comment: I'm using the first one for now (index.php). It might not be ideal, but as I say there is no sensitive data to protect, only scores and user ID's (no personal details or financial info).

Answer (score 1):

If your app accesses the server via normal http requests that means that anybody could do the same from a browser.

You need to make sure that all pages are behind a login system so that only authenticated users have the permissions to do what they can also do from the app itself.

That would seem the easiest way to go if you don't know a lot about the server side of things.

Comment: OK this will be very useful to know for next time, I think now it's probably not convenient to use a login for our existing app since it's already out there so the apps won't have any login details.

Answer (score 1):

Making the folder private would require your app to provide authentication in order to access the pages. Many web servers provide built-in privacy options for folders (Using `.htaccess` files to hide folder contents is a start). How much effort you want to put into protecting this data is only limited by time and your skills as a developer.

If the data you're holding on to is not *that* valuable, nothing stops you from placing a simple conditional `if( $_POST["auth"] != XXXXX )` (or you could use `GET`) at the top of your PHP files which serve your database and then modifying your HTTP requests on your app to provide said key when making requests.

Comment: It already does something kind of similar when going into a subfolder, but since the data is not really of any value at all I've just redirected the folder to our website. I actually took over the project from someone else, and just noticed the reason it returned a table of data is because he has put an index.php in the root folder which did that on purpose - no idea why though.